# Unexpected file being saved when I use VScode + angular + git + protractor

Tags: angular, git, github, visual-studio-code, protractor

When I edit a file in my codebase, unexpected files will be saved like this.

[image]

Please help me with this weird issue.

Comment: What do the files contain? Are they in the root of your repository, or in a subdirectory?

Comment: They are empty files, nothing is in them. They are in the root of my repo. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is similar to "[protractor/issue 4144: Cannot prevent logs and other empty files creation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4144)".

If a `user-data-dir` (in the [angular config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/939)) is incorrectly set to ., that would explain the temp files being generated in your root workspace.

Comment: I checked our protractor.config file, but there is no user-data-dir being set.